# what the different between `pnpm install` and `pnpm add`?

Tags: javascript, monorepo, pnpm

I am work on monorepo stuff, and found that some guys use `pnpm install` to install packages in workspace, but some other use `pnpm add`.

in the pnpm docs, its seem like the same between `add` and `install` command, but there are some different options like `--offline` (for `install`)、`--workspace`(for `add`), and if I use `pnpm install [pkg name] --workspace`, its work normally.

so what the different between `pnpm install` and `pnpm add`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is not much difference between them. In most cases they are interchangeable:

`pnpm install <args?>`: without `args` it will scan and install all the modules listed in `pnpm-lock.yaml`, in case of `args` it works as `pnpm add`

`pnpm add <args>`: It will install one more package.

if choose yes i will use `pnpm add` because it is new modern syntax that supports all package managers (`npm add`, `yarn add`)

Comment: The only difference is that `pnpm add` will fail when executed without args. `pnpm install` will work in both cases. I recommend using `pnpm add` when you add new dependencies because the pnpm tab autocompletion will work better.

Answer (score 9):

Basically as per their docs:

---

We need to use ***`pnpm add`*** when we want to add a new dependency to our project

---

We will be needing to use ***`pnpm install`*** when we have an existing project with the lockfile and we want to install all dependencies from the lockfile.

---

For more information please refer to the official docs:

[PNPM Add Docs](https://pnpm.io/cli/add) 
[PNPM Install Docs](https://pnpm.io/cli/install)

Answer (score 5):

**pnpm add** : Installs **a package** and any packages that it depends on.
**pnpm install** :  is used to install all dependencies for a project.

https://pnpm.io/cli/install 
https://pnpm.io/cli/add